# Determining if a GeoTIFF's projection is in spherical or cartesian coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, utm, spherical-geometry

I have received GeoTIFF that may be projected into a UTM or cartesian coordinate system or may be in a spherical (lat/lon) coordinate system.

Is there a reliable way to automatically determine which of these it is?

Comment: look at the lower left coordinate, if the numbers are below 180E 90N it's geographical, but what datum? Surely there is some metadata that came with the file.

Comment: If gdalinfo reports the projection as `Coordinate System is: PROJCRS...` then it is obviously projected and if the string starts as `GEOGCRS` then it is geographic. I do not know if this is a reliable test for all cases.